# Body request with multipart

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipart

This is my retrofit2 interface

```
@Multipart
@PUT("webservice")
fun setProfile(
    @Part("city") city: RequestBody,
    @Part("name") name: RequestBody,
    @Part("sex") sex: RequestBody,
    @Part("birthday") birthday: RequestBody,
    @Part("about_me") aboutMe: RequestBody,
    @Part img: MultipartBody.Part
): Observable<BaseResponse>
```

That's how I create these RequestBodies:

```
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body.city),
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body.name),
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body.sex),
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body.birthday),
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), body.about_me),
```

My webservice gets data like this:

```
Accept: application/jsonContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="city"    
Tokyo

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"   
John Smith

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sex" 
male

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="avatar.png"
Content-Type: image/png
(img data)
```

When I send my data like described above I get 422 error code with the next description

*field city is required to fill out*

So, as I understood the webservice is unable to find these fields. But when I send data without img, just like @Body it works well. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try this MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data") instead of MediaType.parse("text/plain")

Comment: @CôngHải yeah, actually I tried this right now. Unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: try use @ POST instead of @ PUT

Comment: Test the API in Postman client and [edit] the question, attach the Postman screenshots here.

Comment: @CôngHải POST not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this. I had a long time discussion with backend developer and we found an error. I had to use POST and put into params the next field:

params.put("_method", "PUT")